# Do you use ant's <depend> task?

Tags: java, ant, build

The [documentation for ant's  task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/depend.html) states:

> The performance of the depend task is
>   dependent on a number of factors such
>   as class relationship complexity and
>   how many class files are out of date.
>   The decision about whether it is
>   cheaper to just recompile all classes
>   or to use the depend task will depend
>   on the size of your project and how
>   interrelated your classes are.

I suspect that using the  task before calling  may speed up the build for the project I work on, and possibly prevent the need for clean builds in certain cases.  However, the ant documentation is very cryptic for this task and I could use some clarification.  I work with a large code base containing about 16k classes in src and 4k classes in testsrc.  We build a core jar file containing about a quarter of the classes, followed by about 15 other jars that depend on the core.jar and not each other.  I would just try it out, but our build.xml requires a lot of clean-up before I can make this change, and I want to understand the  task better anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be very careful with this.  There are some things, like declaring constants like this:

```
public static final int FOO = 1;
```

that the depends on task (and javac itself) don't always pick up on (I am not 100% certain that the one above messes with Ant, but I know some things do).

I did use the depend task a long time ago and quickly removed it as I kept needed to do full builds to ensure that things were sane.

Comment: This is a compile time optimization so it's a weakness of <javac> as well.  Obviously there are cases where you still need a clean build.  I'm asking if there are cases where <depend> deletes more files than <javac> recompiles.

Comment: from what I remember it was not enough given that I still had to do clean builds to ensure things were getting built properly.  I decided that depend wasn't safe enough for my needs.

Comment: From what I remember, yes, depend was more correct than javac (just not correct enough to use it over a clean build)