# How can Java build tools stop rebuilding everything?

Tags: java, maven, ant, build, gradle

- **tl;dr Version:** Is there a way I can tell ant/maven/gradle to track file dependencies and only rebuild files which are outdated, i.e., older than their dependencies?
- **long version below:**

### How I did it in C/C++

I used `make` for many years for C/C++. And while it might be cumbersome sometimes, it at least does one of the most important things for me: It tracks file dependencies and only rebuilds a file if any of its dependencies is newer than the file itself. This is great, it reduces build times considerably especially when a lot of code generation tools are executed.

I use a lot of code generation in my projects. However, code generation takes some time and the generated code has to be compiled afterwards, so even more time wasted. Most of the generated code depends only on a small number of files, e.g., a grammar specification when generating a parser. With `make`, I simply set dependencies to the specification file and the parser is only rebuilt when the spec changes. In some of my projects generating the code takes 80-90% of the time a complete rebuild requires. Thus, not having to rebuild generated code speeds up my build process by almost a factor of 10.

### Now to java

People don't use `make` for java, so even if I like make, I also the usual java build tools for my java projects. It seems that the build tools I tried (ant,gradle,maven) do not offer such dependency tracking. Instead, they rely on the called applications or tasks to do this (e.g., the `ant copy` task copies only files which are outdated). However, the code generation programs I use simply do not offer such checks. They always execute the full code generation no matter whether the input specifications are outdated or not.

Consequently, my build times in java got longer and longer. They got so long that I took the code generation out of the usual build cycle into a separate target and only executed this target manually after changing any spec file. But of course, this is error prone since I sometimes forget it. My build process now feels totally flawed.

### Finally, my questions

1. Is there a way to perform dependency tracking and rebuilding only outdated files in any of the build tools I mentioned (ant,gradle,maven) that I am not aware of?
2. If not, then why? Why does the java community not seem to care about this feature? Especially when a lot of code generation is involved, such a feature is extremely important, especially if the code generation tools used do not offer that feature themselves.
3. If not, then are there any other java build tools which do have such tracking?

Answer (score 1):

Some Gradle-centric answers:

Gradle will only rerun a task if its inputs have changed compared to the previous run, or its outputs have been deleted or modified. This is a *generic* feature that works for *any* task as long as it declares its inputs and outputs. (Built-in task types declare their inputs and outputs out-of-the-box.) This feature is often called *incremental build* - a build that only executes a subset of tasks.

Gradle also has (very) experimental support for incremental Java compilation. This is an example for an *incremental task*, i.e. a task that only does a subset of work depending on *which* inputs have changed compared to the previous run. Implementing an incremental task requires knowledge of the task's domain (e.g. Java compilation). As such this feature is less generic than the *incremental build* feature and requires more effort from the task implementor.

To give a concrete example, if your code generation task declares its inputs and outputs (which is very easy to do), it will only be rerun if a grammar file has changed or the generated files have been deleted or modified. (For the purpose of this example, let's assume there can be multiple grammar files.) Additionally, your task implementation could ask Gradle *which* grammar files have changed since the last run, and use this information to only regenerate a subset of files. Obviously this would take effort to implement on your side, and may not be possible to achieve depending on the nature of the underlying tools used by your task.

Some more words on incremental compilation: Incremental compilation is less widespread among Java build tools for several reasons. For one thing, Java compiles much faster than C++. Also, code bases are typically modularized into many smaller compilation units, each of which will only get recompiled if one of its inputs has changed (at least in Gradle). Nevertheless, I'm sure that more Java build tools will support incremental compilation over time. Some already do today (e.g. Pants, sbt, and IDEs such as Eclipse and IntelliJ), and Gradle is about to catch up.

Comment: Interesting answer, thanks! Could you give an example or provide a link for how to declare inputs and outputs for a task in gradle? I favor gradle anyway since I hate XML.

Answer (score 0):

Maven can be used for this. [How does maven compile only the modified java files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772747/how-does-maven-compile-only-the-modified-java-files) is the answer to your question:

> I was just curious to know this, when i give mvn install without doing
>   'clean', maven compiles only the modified java files

The problem is that you regenerate all files. Then you lose track of the unmodified files(all iterated tools compare last modified timestamp between .class and .java). Can you limit the code generation to only really modified files?

If you can't, an idea could be to generate the files in another directory and to write a script to check and replace only modified files in the compiling "area"(by comparing content). After that you can run mvn install.

Comment: I know it works for java to class compiling. But, this is exactly my problem. Not *Maven* tracks this but the compiler plug-in (the `javac` task in ant does so, too). Thus, this works for compiling java but *not* for generating code. Of course, I could use a script, but this would be like totally giving up and doing all the tracking myself.

Comment: No, various 3rd party applications, like, for example, a parser generator and so on.

Comment: The problem is that you don't have outdated files. Everything is shiny new to the compiler (All timestamps are newer). To collaborate with it you must obey to its meaning of outdated. It's that really hard to add a script that only copies the modified files? If you do it, you can rebuild the project easy. Example: generateTool -generate && copyScript && cd ../compileDirectory && mvn install. copyScript should compare files content and copy only if they are changed.

Comment: I found that ant has a task called depend for your scenario. The problem is that is not very reliable because it can miss some changes that should trigger recompilation. Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627868/do-you-use-ants-depend-task

Comment: Incremental compilation in Maven is completely unreliable. Ant doesn't do incremental compilation unless the `depend` task is used, which is also unreliable. Contrary to common belief, the JDK's `javac` command doesn't support incremental compilation (it simply recompiles the files you tell it to).